# xargs doesn't use my "ls" alias

Tags: alias, aix, xargs, hp-ux

On AIX (but this happens on HP-UX as well), I have GNU ls in my path
and it is also aliased as `ls`.

When I use xargs, it instead uses the standard Unix `ls` instead of the
alias.

For example (`flocate` is a function which finds the exact path of
the search subject):

```
flocate mirrorvg | xargs ls -lh
ls: illegal option -- h
usage: ls [-1ACFHLNRSabcdefgiklmnopqrstuxEUX] [File...]

ls -lh /usr/sbin/mirrorvg
-r-xr-x--- 1 root system 37K apr  3  2014 /usr/sbin/mirrorvg*
```

Why doesn't xargs use the `ls` alias?

Comment: What exactly does "I have GNU ls in my path" mean? Is the directory containing the GNU `ls` executable in your `$PATH` environment variable, and does it precede the directory (probably `/bin`) containing the non-GNU `ls` command? Please update your question to show us the actual value of your `$PATH`. `xargs` will execute the *first* `ls` command that it finds in a directory in your `$PATH`; it doesn't know about aliases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command `xargs` is only able to run commands, not aliases. GNU parallel, however, is able to run functions:

```
The command must be an executable, a script, a composed
command, or a function. If it is a function you need to export
-f the function first. An alias will, however, not work (see
why http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=484296).
```

So I would recommend either:

- Giving xargs the full path to the version of ls you want to use (or an unambiguous name, perhaps `gls` depending on how it was installed on your system) or, if your shell allows it,
- Defining `ls` as a function (`function ls { gls "$@"; }; export -f ls` in bash) and using GNU parallel instead of xargs (`parallel -j1` if you would like to use a single CPU).

Comment: exporting functions only works with the `bash` shell. You can use `xargs` with exported functions as well:  `ls() { gls "$@"; }; export -f ls; ... | xargs bash -c '"$0" "$@"' ls`

Comment: Oh, nice trick, it could be useful if one is forced to use xargs.

Comment: You can use `env_parallel` if you want to use aliases or do not want to export the function. Aliases are supported in: ash, bash, csh, dash, fish, ksh, mksh, pdksh, tcsh, zsh. Functions are supported in: bash, fish, ksh, mksh, pdksh, sh, zsh. They even work if you run commands on remote servers. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/env_parallel.html

Answer (score 3):

The alias substitution is done by the shell. If the shell tries to call command `foo`, and there is an alias `foo=bar`, it's the shell that substitutes the `foo` by `bar` here.

The shell only does this for commands. (Otherwise, arguments that happen to be the same as an aliased command would be replaced too.) But your `ls` here is not run by the shell, but an argument to `xargs`. Therefore, the shell does not replace it.

Then `xargs` executes `ls`, but it does not know about the aliases, so it just runs the first one it finds in the path.

The aliases are internal to the shell and there is no standardized way for a program to read them out.

Comment: Note that doing `alias xargs='xargs '` will tell the shell to expand aliases after `xargs`.